# ¿Como hacer una lista sin valores duplicados?

Tags: python, python-3.x

como estan?

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de práctica para aprender Python (Ya que es mi primer lenguaje de programación).

El ejercicio me pide que **recorra un diccionario y cree una lista solo con los valores que contiene, sin añadir valores duplicados.**

Esto es lo que hice:

```py
dicc = {
    'Mikel': 3,
    'Ane': 8,
    'Amaia': 12,
    'Unai': 5,
    'Jon': 8,
    'Ainhoa': 7,
    'Maite': 5
}

lista = []

for i in set(dicc):
    lista.append(dicc[i])
print(lista)
```

**Y me devuelve esto:**

```py
[3, 8, 12, 5, 8, 7, 5]
```

El programa esta bien, pero tengo que hacer que los números dentro de la lista no se repitan (en este caso, el 8 y el 5).
Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos posibles soluciones.

1. Comprobar si el valor existe en la lista
2. Usar `set`(como haces con las keys del diccionario) para borrar los valores duplicados.

Ejemplo 1.

```
dicc = {
    'Mikel': 3,
    'Ane': 8,
    'Amaia': 12,
    'Unai': 5,
    'Jon': 8,
    'Ainhoa': 7,
    'Maite': 5
}

lista = []

for i in set(dicc):
    if dicc[i] not in lista:
        lista.append(dicc[i])
print(lista)
```

Ejemplo 2.

```
dicc = {
    'Mikel': 3,
    'Ane': 8,
    'Amaia': 12,
    'Unai': 5,
    'Jon': 8,
    'Ainhoa': 7,
    'Maite': 5
}

lista = []

for i in set(dicc):
    lista.append(dicc[i])

no_dup = list(set(lista))
print(no_dup)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! :D

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de un generador:

```
lista = [x for x in set(dicc.values())]
```

Esta linea de código añade los valores no repetidos del diccionario a la lista. Donde `x` es la variable que va a obtener todos los valores del set de la lista (este set generador con la función `set()`). A continuación te adjunto como quedaría tu código final y el resultado:

**Solución**

```
dicc = {
    'Mikel': 3,
    'Ane': 8,
    'Amaia': 12,
    'Unai': 5,
    'Jon': 8,
    'Ainhoa': 7,
    'Maite': 5
}

lista = [x for x in set(dicc.values())]
print(lista)
```

**Resultado**

```
[3, 5, 7, 8, 12]
```

Espero te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! :D